# how to convert HuggingFace's Seq2seq models to onnx format

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, onnx

I am trying to convert the Pegasus newsroom in HuggingFace's transformers model to the ONNX format. I followed [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/notebooks/04-onnx-export.ipynb#scrollTo=foYlXrSksR_v) guide published by Huggingface. After installing the prereqs, I ran this code:

```
!rm -rf onnx/
from pathlib import Path
from transformers.convert_graph_to_onnx import convert

convert(framework="pt", model="google/pegasus-newsroom", output=Path("onnx/google/pegasus-newsroom.onnx"), opset=11)
```

and got these errors:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3b37ed1ceda5> in <module>()
      3 from transformers.convert_graph_to_onnx import convert
      4 
----> 5 convert(framework="pt", model="google/pegasus-newsroom", output=Path("onnx/google/pegasus-newsroom.onnx"), opset=11)
      6 
      7 

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/models/pegasus/modeling_pegasus.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, head_mask, encoder_head_mask, past_key_values, inputs_embeds, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    938             input_shape = inputs_embeds.size()[:-1]
    939         else:
--> 940             raise ValueError("You have to specify either decoder_input_ids or decoder_inputs_embeds")
    941 
    942         # past_key_values_length

ValueError: You have to specify either decoder_input_ids or decoder_inputs_embeds
```

I have never seen this error before. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pegasus is a [`seq2seq`](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3215) model, you can't directly convert a `seq2seq` model (encoder-decoder model) using this method. The [`guide`](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/notebooks/04-onnx-export.ipynb#scrollTo=foYlXrSksR_v) is for BERT which is an encoder model. Any only encoder or only decoder transformer model can be converted using this method.

To convert a `seq2seq` model (encoder-decoder) you have to split them and convert them separately, an encoder to onnx and a decoder to onnx. you can follow [this guide](https://github.com/Ki6an/fastT5/blob/8dda859086af631a10ad210a5f1afdec64d49616/fastT5/onnx_exporter.py#L45) (it was done for T5 which is also a `seq2seq` model)

**Why are you getting this error?**

while converting [PyTorch to onnx](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html?highlight=onnx%20export#functions)

```
_ = torch.onnx._export(
                        model,
                        dummy_input,
                        ...
                       )
```

you need to provide a dummy variable to both encoder and to the decoder [separately](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/8923#issuecomment-738811521). by default when converting using this method it provides the encoder the dummy variable. Since this method of conversion didn't accept decoder of this seq2seq model, it won't give a dummy variable to the decoder and you get the above error.
`ValueError: You have to specify either decoder_input_ids or decoder_inputs_embeds`

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. I was finally able to convert a t5 model to onxx and it generated encoder and decoder (and quantised versions of these) models. Is it possible to generate a single torch script out of both encoder and decoder that I can use later? I'm trying, load the onnx_model first from local files, then:  `torch.jit.save(torch.jit.trace(model, [myTokenBatch.input_ids, myTokenBatch.attention_mask]), "./t5-single.pt")` but it's throwing an error: "You have to specify either decoder_input_ids or decoder_inputs_embeds" . How should I approach this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Lavneet, unfortunately, you can't create a single combined model from encoder and decoder, even if you do it you won't be able to use it while inferencing. because the encoder runs only once and the decoder runs several times.

Answer (score 2):

The ONNX export of canonical models from Transformers library is supported out of the box in [Optimum library](https://huggingface.co/docs/optimum/main/en/exporters/onnx/usage_guides/export_a_model) (`pip install optimum`):

```
optimum-cli export onnx --model t5-small --task seq2seq-lm-with-past --for-ort t5_small_onnx/
```

Which will give:

```
.
└── t5_small_onnx
    ├── config.json
    ├── decoder_model.onnx
    ├── decoder_with_past_model.onnx
    ├── encoder_model.onnx
    ├── special_tokens_map.json
    ├── spiece.model
    ├── tokenizer_config.json
    └── tokenizer.json
```

You can check `optimum-cli export onnx --help` for more details. What's cool is that the model can then directly be used with ONNX Runtime in (e.g. here) [ORTModelForSeq2SeqLM](https://huggingface.co/docs/optimum/main/en/onnxruntime/package_reference/modeling_ort#optimum.onnxruntime.ORTModelForSeq2SeqLM).

Pegasus itself is not yet supported, but will soon be: https://github.com/huggingface/optimum/pull/620

Disclaimer: I am a contributor to this lib.

Comment: What is the difference between these two files: `decoder_model.onnx` and `decoder_with_past_model.onnx`?